# How to run Linux Remmina from the terminal?

Tags: fedora-17, rdesktop, remmina

I would like to bring up a Remmina remote desktop from the command line.  I have installed remmina on Fedora 17 Linux.

I type the command `remmina` which prints up a GUI.  It works correctly, I want to make a script which automatically brings up the remote desktop.  But I can't find the command to pass a parameter to do it all in one command.

Is there a way to run remmina and automatically bring up a screen?  How?

Comment: On the command line or in a script, I find `xfreerdp` easier to use than `remmina`.

Answer (score 30):

**You have to create a remmina config file to specify connection parameters.**

```
[el@rosewill bin ]$ remmina -?            
Usage:                                
  remmina [OPTION...] - The GTK+ Remote Desktop Client   

Help Options:                                   
  -h, --help           Show help options        

Application Options:        
  -a, --about          Show about dialog
  -c, --connect=F      Connect to a .remmina file F
  -e, --edit=F         Edit a .remmina file F
  -n, --new            Create a new connection profile
  -p, --pref           Show preference dialog
  -x, --plugin=P       Execute plugin P
  -q, --quit           Quit the application
  -s, --server=S       Use default server name S
  -t, --protocol=T     Use default protocol T
  -i, --icon           Start as tray icon
```

**Create a remmina configuration file**

1. Run the command `remmina` from a user and press the button to "create a new desktop file".
2. Set up that configuration file so you can connect to it through the GUI.
3. Save it and quit.
4. Look in your user directory.  In my case `/home/el/.remmina/` inside there you will find a `something.remmina` file.  That is your configuration file.
5. From the terminal, execute this:

   ```
   remmina -c /home/el/.remmina/1375746771949.remmina
   ```
6. That should have brought up your desktop connection.

**Contents of my configuration file:**

```
[remmina]
disableclipboard=0
ssh_auth=0
clientname=
quality=0
ssh_charset=
ssh_privatekey=
console=0
resolution=1800x900
group=
password=supersecretpassword==
name=HostNameZeusCannon
ssh_loopback=0
shareprinter=0
ssh_username=
ssh_server=
security=
protocol=RDP
execpath=
sound=off
exec=
ssh_enabled=0
username=myusername@gmail.com
sharefolder=
domain=
server=192.168.13.106
colordepth=32
window_maximize=0
window_height=967
viewmode=1
window_width=1812
~
```

**Then I can create a little bash script that calls it up:**

```
remmina -c /home/el/.remmina/1375746771949.remmina
```

Then hook it onto my desktop so it brings up the other screen on a button click.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer on how to use a client certificate for server authentication instead of username and password...

Comment: ah jeez rick this was 8 years ago on Fedora 8? The computer I did this on is lifeless in the cellar.  I've moved on to nomachine software since.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to ;-) these tough Corona times. The cloud provider gave me CER certificate as an authentication token. Works on Windows, works on Mac. Cannot frog the hurdle under Linux unfortunately.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 the location is ~/.local/share/remmina

Answer (score 1):

```
dbus-run-session sshpass -p "password" remmina -c "rdp://username@ipaddress"
```

This seems to mostly work, although it's a bit slow connecting and requires installing sshpass. The session needs to be stopped in the terminal once the Remmina window is closed.

-

*Edit:*

To try sshpass see below. As the name suggests, it also works for ssh sessions.

***Debian/Ubuntu:***
sudo apt-get install sshpass.

***RedHat/CentOS:***
yum install sshpass

***Fedora:***
dnf install sshpass

***Install/User Guide:***
https://www.tecmint.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-login-shell-script-ssh-password/