# Save RDP credentials into file

Tags: remote-desktop

Hi I need to access the same machine via RDP and through different usernames for testing purposes.

I would like to create multiple .rdp files *with passwords* to do that. I do not want the files tied to any machine.

Is that possible?

Comment: Although this may not align precisely with your requirements, it offers a considerable simplification in automating the process of connecting to RDP sessions. Unlike solutions dependent on files, this native approach eliminates the need for a file. You can explore this solution further at https://superuser.com/questions/1782861/remotely-login-to-windows-desktop/1784063#1784063. It serves as a foundational concept that can be expanded, automated, and scaled, as I have successfully executed in various scenarios requiring RDP functionality.

Answer (score 0):

With native RDP, this is not possible.

There are many RDP managers that do support this.

Just to name a few RoyalTS, Devolution's Remote Desktop Manager, and there are many more.

What they allow you to do is create multiple credential items, and then setup the RDP connection and refer to those credential items. It can allow you to ask for one and you select it from the list, or you can store all of them as separate items, and you just double-click the one from the list you want to connect to.